# The '$filter' parameter value is not supported for 'Messages' resource

Tags: api, graph

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user_id/mailfolders/inbox/messages?$filter=receivedDateTime ge %s and receivedDateTime le %s &$orderby=receivedDateTime desc &$top=%s" %(start_date, end_date, mail_no))